Deploy a django application that uses PostgreSQL into a cloud VM
I have a django web application which I would like to deploy in a cloud VM. As of now I am planning to deploy that into AWS EC2. Planning to use gunicorn as WSGIServer and NGINX as web server. I have gone through many documentations all of which explains in a way that the whole source code is present in the VM. Mainly I would like to know how can I package my application and deploy it? For example, in case of web applications using java, we normally creates a war file. How can we do similar thing with django? I am new to Django and Python.
